# Laravel Beanstalkd job cannot connect to remote server via ssh

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, beanstalkd

I've got a workflow in my web application that looks like this (Built in Laravel 4):

1) User uploads a file (up to 50mb or so)
2) File is moved to temp directory
3) Queued job created that does the following:
 - Uploads file to amazon s3
 - SSH into another file processing server and transfers the file to a folder there.
 - Delete the temporary file

To connect to the remote server and upload the file within the queued job, I'm using:

```
SSH::into('processing')->put($localPath, $remotePath);
```

Everything works fine when I queue this job using the 'sync' driver, so I know the environment and permissions are correct.  The problem is, when I switch over to beanstalkd as my queue driver, the job fails with the following:

```
[2015-01-09 14:15:40] production.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to connect to remote server.'
```

Beanstalkd jobs run fine elsewhere in the application (none of the others have ssh commands).

I'm using a username and password for the connection, so it's not a key permissions or passphrase issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file has uploaded OK to S3, why not generate a new job, that will then be run on the other file processing server (step 3b), to have it download the file from S3, if it needs it?

Other than that - you would need more debugging on the SSH upload.

Comment: I think that's ultimately going to be the solution to grab the file.  I just want to know why the SSH connect is failing in case I need to use SSH in a queued job in the future.  The exception is actually being thrown when I SSH into the server to create the directory (which also works fine when run in 'sync' queue mode) and not the file upload.  Thx for the reply. :)